# How can I visually indicate which links are external to my site?

Tags: css

Is it possible with css to visually indicate which links points to another site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CSS3 is an option (this excludes IE6) you could style external links differently, provided your lines are relative and not absolute, what I mean is your links look like this:

```
<a href="/dir/page.htm">My Page</a>
//and external...
<a href="http://www.google.com">External</a>
```

Then you could use the [CSS3 attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to style external links differently, like this:

```
a { color: blue; } /* Internal links */
a[href^=http] { color: red; } /* External Links */
```

[You can see an example of this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/FFf24/)  This uses the attribute "starts-with" selector, anything that has an `href="http...."` will get styled with this rule.  The only alternatives I see are either giving your external (or internal, either one) links a class when they're rendered, or doing the same via javascript.

Comment: personally i would preface an icon that indicates a external link (http://jsfiddle.net/FFf24/4/), the color is not explicit it could be a visited link. but +1 for the CSS selector,

Comment: @meo - I agree that's a *much* stronger visual indicator, `color` was just picked at random to illustrate the style working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with IE6 users being left out, you can use point 4 from [here](http://meganmcdermott.com/2006/10/26/marking-external-links-with-css/).
Otherwise, I'd go with manually adding a class to external links *or* using jQuery (or whatever, getElementsByTagName) and testing if the href contains "http://". If so, I would add a class to those elements. Of course, this would only be acceptable if you are willing to use javascript.